# Can I get a transit visa when I arrive in Istanbul?

Tags: transit-visas, layovers, turkey, pakistani-citizens, visas-on-arrival

I am Pakistani National, living in UK. I am travelling to Pakistan via Turkish Airline. I want to go into Istanbul for a day as my next layover is 28 hours. Can I get transit visa on arrival at the airport desk?

Comment: You are eligible to receive an eVisa. You can get it either from home or at the airport kiosks when you land.

Answer (score 4):

All citizens of Pakistan require a visa in order to enter Turkey, however there are a few different types of visas available.

If you currently hold a valid/unexpired visa or residence permit for a Schengen area country, Ireland, the United Kingdom or the United States, then you will be able to apply for an eVisa, or obtain a visa on arrival once you get to Istanbul.

If you do not hold a visa/residence permit for one of those countries then you will need to apply for a visa in advance, at a Turkish consulate.

In your case, given you've stated you live in the UK, I'm presuming you hold either a UK visa or residence permit, in which case you can get by with only an eVisa.  Officially, presuming you are staying overnight, you will also need a hotel reservation in advance of arriving in the country.

I would strongly suggest obtaining an eVisa in advance rather than waiting until you arrive in Turkey - it's faster, cheaper, and less likely to result in problems - you can obtain one from the [official Turkey e-visa application site](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/).